# Unit Testing With Mediatr pipelines

Tags: .net, xunit, mediatr

I have an api controller which uses Mediatr for a variety of operations. For some of these operations, I need to verify the user has the correct level of access, so I use an authorisation pipeline:

```
public class AuthorisationPipeline<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IAuthorisedRequest<TResponse>
{
    public AuthorisationPipeline()
    {   }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
         //Verify User
    }
}


{
    public interface IAuthorisedRequest : IAuthorisedRequest<Unit>
    { }

    public interface IAuthorisedRequest<out TResponse> : IRequest<TResponse>
    {
        Actor Actor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So any request that needs to be authorised inherits the `IAuthorisedRequest` interface.

This works fine when running the API, however, I've been trying to set up unit tests which run an api call end to end (or functional tests or subcutaneous tests or whatever you want to call them). When I try to run those tests, any request which doesn't inherit IAuthorisedRequest throws the following exception:

`System.ArgumentException : GenericArguments[0], 'UpdateUsers+Command', on 'AuthorisationPipeline2[TRequest,TResponse]' violates the constraint of type 'TRequest'.`

This can be fixed if I remove `where TRequest : IAuthorisedRequest<TResponse>`, but then this pipeline will run for every request, which I would rather avoid. Is there a better way around this issue? What is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into running integration tests on your mediator handlers using the SliceFixture.cs the same way Jimmy Boagrd does.

You can take a look at the tests he has put together in his example application [here](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages/tree/master/ContosoUniversity.IntegrationTests).

I've been using the exact same pattern for years and it works well for subcutaneous testing.